# Create folder on list with custom form

Tags: list, folder, list-form

I have a list that I'm trying to create a folder in. I have gone to the settings to activate the "New Folders" button, but when I click on it, instead of showing me the "New Folder" form, it shows me the "New Item" form. If I fill out the form, it creates an item instead of a folder as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a workflow that created a custom folder, ran it, then deleted the workflow.